# Complex menu design in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a beginner on twitter bootstrap. I have to integrate this image on web site using bootstrap 3. How to make this menu using bootstrap element without adding images? Thank you 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQpVa.png

Answer (score 1):

You can create some white cols (for some li's) inside a black row. Use the hover tag to choose what is appear white or not.

You can create these cols inside a bigger col too.

Hope my words help! :)

Comment: thank you for your answer. My problem is about the circular shape between black and white. Is it possible to do it with css property and no images?

Comment: Yes, it is! You can do almost everything you can do with regular HTML. Just don't use "width" and "height" in col's divs and have a prefere % to px. :)